# How to do cases with an inductive type in Coq

Tags: logic, coq

I wan to use the `destruct` tactic to prove a statement by cases. I have read a couple of examples online and I'm confused. Could someone explain it better?

Here is a small example (there are other ways to solve it but try using `destruct`):

```
 Inductive three := zero 
                  | one 
                  | two.
 Lemma has2b2: forall a:three, a<>zero /\ a<>one -> a=two.
```

Now some examples online suggest doing the following:

```
intros. destruct a.
```

In which case I get:

```
3 subgoals H : zero <> zero /\ zero <> one
______________________________________(1/3) 
zero = two

______________________________________(2/3) 
one = two

______________________________________(3/3) 
two = two
```

So, I want to prove that the first two cases are impossible. But the machine lists them as subgoals and wants me to PROVE them... which is impossible.

Summary:
How to exactly discard the impossible cases?

I have seen some examples using `inversion` but I don't understand the procedure.

Finally, what happens if my lemma depends on several inductive types and I still want to cover ALL cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How to discard impossible cases? Well, it's true that the first two obligations are impossible to prove, but note they have contradicting assumptions (`zero <> zero` and `one <> one`, respectively). So you will be able to prove those goals with `tauto` (there are also more primitive tactics that will do the trick, if you are interested).

`inversion` is a more advanced version of destruct. Additional to 'destructing' the inductive, it will sometimes generate some equalities (that you may need). It itself is a simple version of `induction`, which will additionally generate an induction hypothesis for you.

If you have several inductive types in your goal, you can `destruct/invert` them one by one.

More detailed walk-through:

```
Inductive three := zero | one | two .

Lemma test : forall a, a <> zero /\ a <> one -> a = two.
Proof.
  intros a H.
  destruct H. (* to get two parts of conjunction *)
  destruct a. (* case analysis on 'a' *)
(* low-level proof *)
  compute in H. (* to see through the '<>' notation *)
  elimtype False. (* meaning: assumptions are contradictory, I can prove False from them *)
  apply H.
  reflexivity.
(* can as well be handled with more high-level tactics *)
  firstorder.
(* the "proper" case *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me another way to prove the goals without tauto? If you don't mind posting a pice of code would be great.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a complete low-level proof. Such low-level stuff is useful to learn things, but in general you'd just do away with it with tactics such as `tauto` or `firstorder`

Answer (score 10):

If you see an impossible goal, there are two possibilities: either you made a mistake in your proof strategy (perhaps your lemma is wrong), or the hypotheses are contradictory.

If you think the hypotheses are contradictory, you can set the goal to `False`, to get a little complexity out of the way. `elimtype False` achieves this. Often, you prove `False` by proving a proposition `P` and its negation `~P`; the tactic `absurd P` deduces any goal from `P` and `~P`. If there's a particular hypothesis which is contradictory, `contradict H` will set the goal to `~H`, or if the hypothesis is a negation `~A` then the goal will be `A` (stronger than `~ ~A` but usually more convenient). If one particular hypothesis is obviously contradictory, `contradiction H` or just `contradiction` will prove any goal.

There are many tactics involving hypotheses of inductive types. Figuring out which one to use is mostly a matter of experience. Here are the main ones (but you will run into cases not covered here soon):

- `destruct` simply breaks down the hypothesis into several parts. It loses information about dependencies and recursion. A typical example is `destruct H` where `H` is a conjunction `H : A /\ B`, which splits `H` into two independent hypotheses of types `A` and `B`; or dually `destruct H` where `H` is a disjunction `H : A \/ B`, which splits the proof into two different subproofs, one with the hypothesis `A` and one with the hypothesis `B`.
- `case_eq` is similar to `destruct`, but retains the connections that the hypothesis has with other hypotheses. For example, `destruct n` where `n : nat` breaks the proof into two subproofs, one for `n = 0` and one for `n = S m`. If `n` is used in other hypotheses (i.e. you have a `H : P n`), you may need to remember that the `n` you've destructed is the same `n` used in these hypotheses: `case_eq n` does this.
- `inversion` performs a case analysis on the type of a hypothesis. It is particularly useful when there are dependencies in the type of the hypothesis that `destruct` would forget. You would typically use `case_eq` on hypotheses in `Set` (where equality is relevant) and `inversion` on hypotheses in `Prop` (which have very dependent types). The `inversion` tactic leaves a lot of equalities behind, and it's often followed by `subst` to simplify the hypotheses. The `inversion_clear` tactic is a simple alternative to `inversion; subst` but loses a little information.
- `induction` means that you are going to prove the goal by induction (= recursion) on the given hypothesis. For example, `induction n` where `n : nat` means that you'll perform integer induction and prove the base case (`n` replaced by `0`) and the inductive case (`n` replaced by `m+1`).

Your example is simple enough that you can prove it as “obvious by case analysis on `a`”.

```
Lemma has2b2: forall a:three, a<>zero/\a<>one ->a=two.
Proof. destruct a; tauto. Qed.
```

But let's look at the cases generated by the `destruct` tactic, i.e. after just `intros; destruct a.`. (The case where `a` is `one` is symmetric; the last case, where `a` is `two`, is obvious by reflexivity.)

```
H : zero <> zero /\ zero <> one
============================
 zero = two
```

The goal looks impossible. We can tell this to Coq, and here it can spot the contradiction automatically (`zero=zero` is obvious, and the rest is a first-order tautology handled by the `tauto` tactic).

```
elimtype False. tauto.
```

In fact `tauto` works even if you don't start by telling Coq not to worry about the goal and wrote `tauto` without the `elimtype False` first (IIRC it didn't in older versions of Coq). You can see what Coq is doing with the `tauto` tactic by writing `info tauto`. Coq will tell you what proof script the `tauto` tactic generated. It's not very easy to follow, so let's look at a manual proof of this case. First, let's split the hypothesis (which is a conjunction) into two.

```
destruct H as [H0 H1].
```

We now have two hypotheses, one of which is `zero <> zero`. This is clearly false, because it's the negation of `zero = zero` which is clearly true.

```
contradiction H0. reflexivity.
```

We can look in even more detail at what the `contradiction` tactic does. (`info contradiction` would reveal what happens under the scene, but again it's not novice-friendly). We claim that the goal is true because the hypotheses are contradictory so we can prove anything. So let's set the intermediate goal to `False`.

```
assert (F : False).
```

Run `red in H0.` to see that `zero <> zero` is really notation for `~(zero=zero)` which in turn is defined as meaning `zero=zero -> False`. So `False` is the conclusion of `H0`:

```
apply H0.
```

And now we need to prove that `zero=zero`, which is

```
reflexivity.
```

Now we've proved our assertion of `False`. What remains is to prove that `False` implies our goal. Well, `False` implies any goal, that's its definition (`False` is defined as an inductive type with 0 case).

```
destruct F.
```