# How to prove the lemma "(P \/ Q) /\ ~P -> Q." in coq?

Tags: coq

I tried to prove this lemma with the tatics [intros], [apply], [assumption], [destruct],[left], [right], [split] but failed. Can anyone teach me how to prove it?

```
Lemma a : (P \/ Q) /\ ~P -> Q.
proof.
```

And generally, how to prove the easy propositions such as false->P, P/~P, etc?

Comment: See also [How to do cases with an inductive type in Coq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823301/how-to-do-cases-with-an-inductive-type-in-coq), which discusses a different but related lemma

Comment: @cachuanghu please note that although it is not necessary, it is customary, and you'll get a couple of reputation points, if you mark an answer that is good enough for you as "accepted". Your comment indicates that you found your way through your difficulty. If none of the answers here contained your way, you may feel free to write your own answer and mark it as "accepted". An accepted answer will be helpful to people like me who are still learning some of these Coq tactics.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have voted for the accepted answer. And is there any thing else should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tactic that you are missing is *contradiction*, which is used in order to prove goals containing contradictory hypotheses. Because you aren't permitted to use contradiction, I believe the lemma you are intended to *apply* is the induction principle for *False*. After doing so, you can *apply* the negated proposition and close the branch by *assumption*. Note that you can do better than your instructor requested, and use *none* of the listed tactics! The proof term for disjunctive syllogism is relatively easy to write:

```
Definition dis_syllogism (P Q : Prop) (H : (P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬P) : Q :=
  match H with
    | conj H₁ H₂ =>
      match H₁ with
      | or_introl H₃ => False_ind Q (H₂ H₃)
      | or_intror H₃ => H₃
      end
  end.
```

Comment: or also, prove the theorem using tactics, and then simply "Print" it to figure out what it is.

Comment: well the tactic would be `apply (False_ind Q (H₂ H₃))`, so it's the same thing; but you need to figure out how to write proof terms eventually if you want to start using dependent types well, so propositional logic is a good starting point.

Comment: yes, and "contradiction," etc.., will also build this same term, I believe.  (Worth noting, even if you use a tactic which seems "simpler," where you can see apply False as being low level, it will still build the same proof term under the covers.)

Comment: well `contradiction` is the simplest way, and you already gave a standard proof that didn't use built-in decision procedures; but the op wanted a proof using only the listed tactics, so i translated the use of `contradiction` into a "lower-level" construct.

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all!  I think it's important to see the connection, that's all.  It's great to have both solutions, and yours is more appropriate than mine wrt the machinery!  Apologies if I seemed not to agree with you, I just think it's important to see that these two methods are one and the same!

Comment: Ah, okay. Well yours is certainly the most appropriate with respect to style. In `Tactics.v`, it says that `contradiction` uses `elim`, so I think also that it should be the same proof term.

Comment: from the manual: "This tactic is a macro for the tactics sequence intros; elimtype False; assumption."

Comment: Well I would like to add that if the statement of the exercises restricts tactics, the answer should stick to the given tactics.  When dealing with negation or False, the leading idea is to use **destruct**.  Then students should learn to do it by themselves, by trial and erro.

Answer (score 3):

```
Section Example.

  (* Introduce some hypotheses.. *)
  Hypothesis P Q : Prop.

  Lemma a : (P \/ Q) /\ ~P -> Q.
    intros.
    inversion H.
    destruct H0.
      contradiction.
      assumption.
  Qed.

End Example.
```

Comment: This example could use a little explanation!

Answer (score 2):

To prove all these easy things, you have the family of tactics `tauto`, `rtauto`, `intuition` and `firstorder`.

I believe they are all stronger than tauto, which is a complete decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional logic.

Then, `intuition` allows you to put in some hints and lemmas to use, and firstorder can reason about first-order inductives.

More details in the [doc](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/tactic-index.html) of course, but these are the kind of tactics you want to use on such goals.

Comment: Tks. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `~P` means `P->False`, and inverting a `False` hypothesis finishes the goal (since `False` has no constructors).  So you really just need `apply` and `inversion`.

```
Lemma a : forall (P Q:Prop), (P \/ Q) /\ ~P -> Q.
Proof.
  intros. 
  inversion H.
  inversion H0.
  - apply H1 in H2.  (* applying ~P on P gives H2: False *)
    inversion H2.
  - apply H2.
Qed.
```